# Autocomplete not working with custom classes in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7

In my Xcode projects for the last couple of days I encountered a problem with autocompletion. If I were to create a class called, for example, MDRViewController and then at the top of My AppDelegate.m file used import "MDRViewController.h" it would not autocomplete when I wanted to create an instance of MDRViewController inside of AppDelegate.m .

It is able to autocomplete for all of the standard foundation classes NSString, NSArray etc. but not for custom classes. I have tried clearing the derived data and reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: If your xcode says it is indexing, autocomplete will not work. LEt the xcode complete indexing or any process it is doing like proceesing the symbols , building etc...

Comment: Indexing takes FOREVER!!  :(

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me with a newly-created class that somehow wasn't included in the Compile Sources list of the target's Build Phases. Once I added the class there, auto-complete started working normally for that class.